# Beamer frametitle now overlapping background canvas

Tags: beamer

Last summer I added a sidebar to the edge of each slide in my beamer presentations, based on my company's PowerPoint template.

However, if I compile my latex beamer files now, the slides with a frametitle puts an ugly white box over my sidebar.

This has stopped working on recent version of LaTeX, as it worked fine last year. I've tried re-compiling presentations from last year, and now these new pdf-files also look wrong.

Minimum example code below, + [sidebar.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3xG5.jpg)

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

% Place company side bar:
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[opacity=1] at (current page.west)
  {\hspace{0.3em}
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{sidebar}};
}

\title{Titlepage looks OK}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t, plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A title}
  See, now title puts a white box is above the bar in the margin

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of white box]

I'm on Arch Linux, and my current latex-version:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.35
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.67.0
```

If anyone has any suggestions how to fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7g2t.png) is what I see. No interference by the title on the second frame. Typically, with node positions using pages, you'll have to compile twice on the first go.

Comment: Which beamer version do you have?

Comment: Recently there had been a version of beamer with a similar bug, but without knowing which beamer version you have it is hard to diagnose if this is indeed the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Werner, thanks, that's definitely not what I'm seeing, even after 5 recompilations.

Comment: @samcarter when compiling the code above, I get: `beamer 2018/09/02 v3.52 A class for typesetting presentations`, and `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5`, and `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux)` (in reverse order, due to relevant version came last).

Comment: @JohanA This is exactly the version which had the colour bug. Can you update to the current version 3.54?

Comment: @JohanA If updating is not possible, try to place this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your current working folder.

Comment: @samcarter indeed that fixed the problem. I downgraded to 3.50, as the bug fix isn't in the latest package in Arch Linux just yet, and I'd like to stick to my OS' package management. It's working fine now, and this issue can be marked as resolved (if that's how this forum works). Thanks a lot, I have my presentation tomorrow, so looking good!

Comment: @JohanA Glad to hear it is working! Good luck with your presentation!